# Visual Studio Update 17.8.0 killed my MAUI application which was running fine until this morning

Tags: android, visual-studio, maui

I am quite desperate here. I have a deadline coming, and my VisualStudio is completely messed up now.

I had several MAUI solutions working fine under "Pixel5 - API 33" on my development machine until this very morning.

My bad - I had the terrible inspiration to accept the update proposed by Visual Studio 2022, thus going from Visual Studio Version I-Don't-Remember-Which-Version-I-Had to version 17.8.0

Now all my previous MAUI solutions won't work - they cannot be run in Visual Studio as MAUI apps. The project properties don't even contain the required sections.

I can only run my old MAUI app as Windows Machine, and nothing else.

I have started a new dummy MAUI project, doing absolutely nothing, you know, the template, and that has completely other properties than my previous MAUI projects. For this one, I can see Pixel5 - API 33, Windows Machine, Android Emulators, iOS local devices, iOS Emulators, etc - the whole list, you know.

But for my "OLD" MAUI app (from this morning "old") I can only see Windows Machine. Of course, the Properties page for them are now completely different.

What has happened ? Did the Visual Studio update mess up my solution ? I am sure it has. I have compared the two sln files in Notepad++ and I cannot find differences.

This is all I have as choices for my MAUI app:

[image: Choices]

These are the desired choices:

[image]

These are my project properties now:

[image]

And these are the project properties I should have:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried command prompt `dotnet workload install maui` ?

Comment: Stephen, Yes, I have tried that. No dice. So: I can start a new MAUI app with the required settings. I cannot load ANY previous MAUI app from my machine, which were running fine until today's lunch break when I accepted MS's offer to update Visual Studio. I don't want to have to REDO my solution (import all classes, all packages, to a redo a lot of settings, etc (it was a complex a large app !) I have to show the product working to the customer in a few days, and....

Comment: And `dotnet workload list` + `dotnet workload update` ?

Comment: You can download the previous version of VS, there's a list here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-history

Comment: Finally ! Thank you very much ! I have reverted VS2022 to two (not just one, but two - I was overly cautious here) versions back, and, suddenly, my solution works again just fine, as it was before ! Magic ! I have wasted more than half a day on this stupid shht ! With the latest version of VS 2022 it was not even recognizing the line "public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()" anymore ! Microsoft, this is not nice at all !!!

Comment: Fabulous.  I just got bit by this too.  I've warned the rest of the dev team to NOT upgrade VS 2022 because it is totally broken wrt a Maui app.  Reverting to the previous VS doesn't fix it.  Going to try rolling back even further

Comment: Just so that you know, when I updated my projects VS2022 told me that, at the very least, I needed to have explicit PackageReference added whereas in my net7.0 projects those references were implicit. Such things include `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />` in your csproj. Anyhow, hope your transition is more seemless and that you do in a explorative dev machine rather than on a production critical machine.

Comment: It was disaster for me as well. I wasted so much time downloading, installing testing, uninstalling and reinstalling 17.6.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem, in my case was not necessary the VS version, because when I reverted to the previous version, It was still broken.
Uninstalling .NET 8 SDK seems to help together with reverting to version 17.7.6 Visual Studio for Windows

Answer (score 1):

According to Andreas Koder, as an answer:

Rolling back Visual Studio to a previous version can fix the issue.