# Cannot run Maui project after migration to Visual Studio version 17.8.3

Tags: visual-studio, maui

I have a project (using .NET6, on VS 17.6) and I am interested in migrating it to .NET8. I have updated VS Community 2022 to 17.8.3. After the update, I got a situation very similar to [Visual Studio Update 17.8.0 killed my MAUI application which was running fine until this morning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77487927/visual-studio-update-17-8-0-killed-my-maui-application-which-was-running-fine-un) (exactly the same changes in the Properties menu. I can’t target different platforms any longer).
Further more, I am now unable to build it (Even on a Windows Machine) due to many errors which seem to indicate that MAUI is not installed (e.g. “type or namespace name ‘MauiWinUIApplication’ could not be found”).
On VS Installer, .NET Multi-platform App UI development is checked.

I have also tried:

`dotnet workload install maui`

MAUI was successfully installed (even though it should have been already installed to version 8 during the migration to VS 17.8.3. I did not check if it were true,  but anyway).

`dotnet workload list` returns this:

Installed Workload Id      Manifest Version       Installation Source

---

maui                       8.0.3/8.0.100          SDK 8.0.100

maui-windows               8.0.3/8.0.100          VS 17.8.34330.188, VS 17.9.34407.89

maccatalyst                17.0.8490/8.0.100      VS 17.8.34330.188, VS 17.9.34407.89

ios                        17.0.8490/8.0.100      VS 17.8.34330.188, VS 17.9.34407.89

android                    34.0.52/8.0.100        VS 17.8.34330.188, VS 17.9.34407.89

I have tried `dotnet workload update`

And after this, the properties menu is different, the section “Application” has completely disappeared after dotnet workload update. This is what I get on Properties of the project:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTm1h.png)

I have tried to modify in the .csproj the target framework from net6.0 to net8.0 as I understand the VS installer may uninstall the net6.0 SDK during the VS update. I did not check if this is true though because changing the target framework to net8.0 on the csproj does not change anything in the above problems.

I have also added  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.3" />as recommended by VS 2022 17.8.3 to the project (I had the message "Starting with .NET 8, setting  <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>  does not automatically include NuGet package references in your project.  Update your project by including this item:  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.3" />. ")

Finally, I have exactly the same problems if I am using VS Preview.

I know I could (should ?) revert to an older VS version or/and uninstall net8.0 but by naïve hope would be to use the latest VS released with net8.0 and to migrate my MAUI project accordingly

Maybe I have been wrong trying .net6.0 + MAUI 8 (right after the migration) but .net8.0 + MAUI 8 does not run either. I still don't understand what to do.

Has anyone an idea what is going on and how to fix the problems explained ?

Comment: Please try to create a new .net8 MAUI project to see if the properties menu appears devices with different platforms normally. Besides, if it's convenient for you, please provide more information about the errors reported when running the program on Windows platforms.

Comment: When I create a new .net8 MAUI project, the properties menu is OK with different platform as with previous versions. On my project, 3 errors which were not there of course before the changes of VS/.net/MAUI versions:  "the type or namespace name 'MauiWinUIApplication' could not be found" / The type or namespace name 'Windowing' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.UI' / 'App' does not contain a definition for 'InitializeComponent'

Comment: Please show the project file. I suspect there's something wrong or missing there.